# arguments are different error for mockservice in junit

Tags: mockito, junit4

I am trying to update the junit by passing an object but I am getting "Arguments are different error"

Here is my code:
I updated the existing dataController, dataService

DataController:

```
 old method:

    List<String> clientData= dataService .retrieveClientData(user, Clientroperties.product);
             updated to:
    dataIdCollector dataIdCollector = new dataIdCollector();
    List<String> clientData= dataService .retrieveClientData(user, Clientroperties.product, dataIdCollector);
```

Here is the dataService class

```
 DataService:
    List<String> clientData retrieveClientData(user, Clientroperties.product, dataIdCollector){
    List<ClientDetails> details = dataDao.getDetails(user, Clientroperties.product);
    dataIdCollector.collectIds(details);
    return serailizeClientDetails(details);
    }
```

I was trying to update the junit by passing dataIdCollector object

```
  dataIdCollector dataIdCollector = new dataIdCollector();

     when(mockService.retrieveClientData(user, Clientroperties.product, dataIdCollector))
     .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("abc"));
  String result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                get("/rest" + RestApiRequestMapping.clientData)

                        .with(credentials)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();                  

     verify(mockService).retrieveClientData(user, Clientroperties.product,dataIdCollector);
```

here  mockMVC endpoint is calling a method in dataController .The dataIdCollector object again created in controller class and causing "Arguments are different " error.
how to fix this issue in junit?

```
 Argument(s) are different!Wanted:

 dataIdCollector@1fb71788

 Actual invocations have different arguments:

 dataIdCollector@8cb7185
```

the mockservice is not updating dataIdCollector object,why it is still getting "different argument.." error.

Comment: You havent shown us how yor srevice gets an instance of dataIdCollector, nor specified if 2 instances of this class should be considersd equivalent

Comment: From the error I would say you use different objects in your test and in the real implementation. They are not considered equal, most likely you do not implement a proper `hashcode` and `equals` methods in your `dataIdCollector` class.

Comment: after implemented hashcode and equals ,it is working.Thank you so much.